# How can I get all tweets by keyword a different method than selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, scrape

I can get tweets from selenium bot this working slow. I need the quick one. Thank you already.

Comment: Show us the code that you've tried so far ?

Comment: Maybe you can describe a bit more your use-case and maybe you can give us some code which you tried and failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from scraping with Selenium, you could request an API key from twitter. They have a python library that can be used to execute queries.

https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this.

Comment: @YusufÖZKAN you're welcome. Please mark the question as solved if this answer addressed your question.